# What happens to number 3?

Tags: power-series

I'm reviewing a text on Maclaurin series. This is more of an algebraic question, anyway. How do we go from here:

$$ z^2e^{3z} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^2(3z)^n}{n!}$$

to here:

$$ z^2e^{3z} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}z^{n+2} $$

It looks like 3^n became z^n. Is this possible?

Comment: Clearly a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the $3^n$ to $z^n$.  This is a typo.